# How to add a user bar to a Laravel layout template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've recently started creating a layout template for my Laravel project following the method stated on here:

https://selftaughtcoders.com/from-idea-to-launch/lesson-20/creating-a-laravel-5-blade-layout-to-standardize-your-pages-appearance/

It seems easy enough to wrap a view with a 'master' layout. However, my layout includes a userbar in the top right (kind of like SO's) which has the user's avatar and username.

What is the best way to do this? I can't imagine I have to pass it through to every view that extends my master layout, but at the moment, it seems that is the only answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your master layout you can simply add the user bar and wrap it in the blade helper `@auth` like this

```
@auth
    This will only be shown when a user is logged in.
@endauth
```

Check the [control structures](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#control-structures) from the documentation for more detailed information.

Comment: What about control data based off certain permissions/settings? I noticed there is 'Service Injection', I'm wondering if that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: You can use your guards by adding `@auth('admin')` as a parameter. If you're talking about third-party permissions etc then I would have to see the package before I can help.

Answer (score -1):

I think you will first need to add an separate element in some element folder. This could be the first step to perform.

Secondly, once you are done with the first step, you will also have to extend the element with @extends() function in main layout.

I hope this helps.